# Sample Size Question - Population- Multiple Regression?

Tags: regression, hypothesis-testing, multivariate-analysis, sample, gpower

I am doing a research project for class. Our research questions are as follows:

1. Has news exposure impacted parental decision-making in preparation for the new school year?
2. Has Media exposure to violence impacted parental decision-making in preparation for the new school year?
3. Have school shooting impacted parental decision-making in preparation for the new school year?

Three IVs we believe may predict DV. However, I do not understand the nuances of differences between t tests, f tests, exact tests, etc. Best guess I have is it is multiple regression? But what specifically? I am trying to determine sample size and will eventually also need to know how to analyze the data. Also, I believe the variables are categorical, based on self-report scales. Parental decision-making, is also via self-report, we ask scale based questions on how often they have thought about changing their child's school, how many items have they've shopped for that will help keep child safe, how often do they train their child in ways to stay safe? All likert based questions, mostly with 3 options.

Comment: How have you operationalized "parental decision making for the new school year"?

Comment: Hello, yes, I added it to the bottom of the post. But, it is also self-report based questions most with 3 option likert scale.